# Smooth Rotation of a Cube In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written a script which rotates the cube, but it sounds like there is kind of air resistance when rotating the cube in air or when it hits with stairs (made by cubes with cube collider).

I have tried the following code, but before this I used addTorque but that also didn't work:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
            input = false;
            StartCoroutine("moveLeft");
}

void moveLeft()
{
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.left;

    Vector3 pivot = Player.transform.position;
    pivot += moveDirection * 0.5f; 
    pivot -= Vector3.up * 0.5f;  
    Vector3 axis = Vector3.forward;
    float degrees = 90;  
    StartCoroutine(FlipOverEdge(degrees, pivot, axis));
}

IEnumerator FlipOverEdge(float degrees, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 axis)
{
    int frames = 12;  
    float degreesPerFrame = degrees / (float)frames;
    for (int i = 1; i <= frames; i++)
    {
        Player.transform.RotateAround(pivot, axis, degreesPerFrame);
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
    input = true;
 }
```

The cube should rotate something like in the following video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fo-7kKeb-TM

Comment: Your calculations seem to assume framerate is fixed

Comment: So what is actually the problem? And yes you should use something like `degrees * Time.deltaTime` instead of using `degreesPerFrame`

Comment: And you know that you only rotate 90 degress when not on a corner ... than you have to rotate 180°, right?

Comment: @derHugo the problem is it pulls back when moving fast and it is colliding with stair, it doesn't leave me to go forward rather pushes back

Comment: @derHugo I also use projectile motion along with projectile motion I use key to rotate it, but it faces some kind of hurdle to move